# Задать пробел в серии паспорта JS

Tags: javascript, str-replace

Подскажите, передается значение серии и номера паспорта в таком виде 1234 567890. Мне нужно, чтобы серия и номер были преобразованы в такой вид 12 34 567890 для последующей передачи в http запрос. Подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: substring + пробел+ substring

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = "1234 567890"
console.log(s.match(/\d{6}(?=\s*$)|\d\d/g).join(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. строки менять нельзя, нам необходимо будет создать новую строку. Самый простой способ, это вызвать метод substring. Можно также воспользоваться методами slice или substr

> Методы работы со строками можно почитать здесь -> https://learn.javascript.ru/string

```js
let pass = '1234 567890'
// Для понимания, что делаем
function passChange(pass) {
  let x = pass.substring(0, 2);
  let y = pass.substring(2);
  return x + ' ' + y
}
console.log(passChange(pass));

// Экономим помять
function passChange2(pass) {
  return pass.substring(0, 2) + ' ' + pass.substring(2);
}

console.log(passChange2(pass));
```

Comment: думаете "компилятор" за вас память не сэкономит?

Comment: @teran Компилятор вообще память экономить не будет, а вот сборщику мусора придется зачищать место выделенное под переменные.

Comment: @SwaD, и с каких пор переменные зачищаются сборщиком мусора?

Comment: @teran, какую память?